# How are IP addresses and port numbers encapsulated down the TCP/IP stack?

Tags: networking, tcpip

This apparently senseless question keeps spinning in my head. I probably wrongly assumed that the Layer 7 headers for different protocols included the source and destination IP addresses and port numbers, so that when they’re passed down to lower layers, protocols at layers 4 will read the port numbers and include them in their own headers (such as TCP or UDP headers), and protocols at layer 3 would read the IP addresses and insert them into the IP packet.

So I guess it is the applications themselves that hand out the port numbers and src and dest IP addresses to protocols in layers 3 and 4.

I’m just curious to learn how this is basically processed down the stack.

Any insight much appreciated

Comment: http://what-when-how.com/data-communications-and-networking/tcpip-example-data-communications-and-networking/

Comment: I'd imagine different OS handle this differently. I'm pretty sure applications don't "hand out" the ports. What research have you done on this? Network systems are pretty documented, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great answers.  This has been completely clarified on the article Hannu posted and confirms what music2myear said.

The port numbers are passed to the transport layer software separately from the layer 7 header, while the IP addresses are passed to the IP software in layer 3, I guess by the application layer software (such as http) or maybe by the OS.  That is: the layer 7 packet contains the data that will be passed to lower layers for delivery.

I checked some headers with Wireshark:

- DNS: the port numbers are not included in the header.  Neither the IP address of the DNS server.
- HTTP: doesn’t include IP addresses or port numbers.

Thanks again, what would I do without you guys!